# How do I achieve a certain TPS in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am given a task in which I have to test my app for an hour with 300 TPS.
I have added my HTTP req in Jmeter and I need to configure below parameters to achieve my target

- target concurrency
- Ramp up time
- Ramp-up steps
- Hold target
- thread iteration limit

I could guess by name few of these but still I am not quiet sure how to work around it to achieve my target. I am new to Jmeter can any one please help.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're talking about [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) so answers are:

- **target concurrency** - we don't know, it depends on your application response time, i.e. if response time is 1 second - go for `300`, if response time is 2 seconds - go for `600`, etc. If you don't know the response time you can put "sufficient" number of concurrent threads, for example `1000` and use [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) for limiting the load to 300 TPS

  [image]
- **Ramp up time** - again, we don't know your requirements. I can only recommend increasing the load **gradually** so you could correlate increasing load with increasing response time or number of errors so for example start with 1 TPS and increase the load to 300 TPS in i.e. 15 minutes and leave it running for 1 hour

  [image]
- **Ramp-up steps** - again, we don't know your requirements, start with above recommendation and adjust ramp-up period up or down as needed
- **Hold target** - at least 60 minutes or 3600 seconds plus any ramp-up time
- **thread iteration limit** - leave blank otherwise your test may end earlier than you expect

Example Concurrency Thread Group combination:

[image]

the values given in [Schedule Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function) are for reference only, the example means that the Concurrency Thread Group will start 1000 threads initially with maximum of 1500 threads and have 300 spare threads in pool, hopefully it will be sufficient to produce 300 TPS load which is set by the Throughput Shaping Timer

Comment: My apps response time is around 45-50ms, so it means I should be adding target concurrency as 0.045*300 .. isn't it too low?